# Can LISA observe BH beyond the observable universe?

Tags: gravitational-waves, interferometry, observable-universe

Reading the paper "Astro2020 Science White Paper
[Where are the Intermediate Mass Black Holes?](https://lisa.nasa.gov/downloads/forScientists/whitePapers/Where_IMBHs.pdf)", and the plot in Fig.1, page 5, it seems LISA can see IMBH beyond 100 Gpc...Since the observable universe is about 14-50 Gpc, does it mean LISA can observe beyond the observable Universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the graph in question:

[image: Graph]

The distance shown on the right axis is the [luminosity distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_distance) not actual distance. At high red shifts the luminosity is decreased by various effects so it is far lower than a simple inverse square law predicts, and hence the luminosity distance is greater than the actual distance. The actual distance, or more precisely the *comoving radial distance*, for a red shift of 20 is about 36 billion light years. For comparison the edge of the observable universe is currently about 46 billion light years away.

Comment: So LISA could see more than the Hubble and even the JWST, and see 36=3(46/4)=3x11.5~75% of the whole known-size Universe...Not bad at all...Hardly we could see redshift 20 in optical right now...And waiting, if i live long enough, to see the 21-cm radiotelescope on the moon to see the reionization era map of the Universe (if I am lucky...of course).

Comment: A relation between the comoving radial distance and luminosity distance should be great as well for completion in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @riemannium Calculating the luminosity distance is quite complicated. That should be a separate question.